# Two Workers don't run at once

Tags: java, swingworker

The SwingWorkers work only if I don't call the same method.

```
public class JavaApplication89
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Worker1 w1=new Worker1();
        Worker2 w2=new Worker2();
        try
        {w1.execute(); w2.doInBackground();}
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

If I call execute on both or doInBackground on both, nothing happens.

Here's the code for Worker1 and Worker2:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void,Void>
{
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=1000;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            try
            {sleep(1000);}
            catch (InterruptedException ex){}
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If I give up on Worker1 and Worker2 and write only one class called Worker, the output doesn't come simultaneously, the second output waits for the first one.
Can you please explain me what is the matter?

Comment: Please explain, what you want to achieve and why you use SwingWorker? Main purpose of SwingWoker is to run long tasks in a different to EDT thread.

Comment: I want to get an output like "1 1 2 2 3 3 ... 1000 1000"

Comment: And what you get now? Please provide the complete text of your program.

Comment: Oh! I think I know what the problem is. The processes started by the workers go on, but there is nothing that the main process does, so the debugging ends.
By the way, it only showed BUILD SUCCESSFUL.

Comment: It works perfectly if I write sleep(10000) at the end of main. Should I delete this dumb question?

Comment: It's not a dumb question. It's good to know that SwingWorker does not work properly without Swing :)